# How much status damage (like bleed) do I need to deal to proc the effect (i.e. blood loss)?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I am a bit confused when it comes to the status effects like Frostbite or Bleed: I know that when I am at the receiving end of such damage, the meter at the bottom of the screen fills with each attack and when it reaches the end, the status effect takes place and I get bonus damage (Frostbite, blood loss etc).

But how much damage do I need to take (or give)?

For example, +5 Frayed blade deals 41 bleed damage with each attack. My character has 369 bleed resistance and 166 bleed armour. How many hits from the Frayed Blade can I take before I get the Blood loss and how much will I lose? Is it simply 369/41 = 9 hits or maybe 166/41 = 4.04 hits?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You have to surpass the Resistance in order to proc the status effect.**

For instance, in your example you need to reach 370 in the bleed gauge to suffer bloodloss.

**The effect of status effect is fixed by the stats and weapon used.**

Status effect's damage can be flat, a % of max hp or both. They can depend on the weapon used and stats of the player which procced the status or buffs. But the receiver has no way to modify the damage.

More info on status damage can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DkS3Builds/comments/64g5da/bleed_poison_frostbite_toxic_buildups_after_111/)

**The Armor column represent how much Resistance you gain from equipped pieces of armor.**

You can ignore it.

---

Following your example, 9 hits are required to proc bloodloss. Remember that the gauge falls over time, so you may require more hits to actually proc the status.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://steamcommunity.com/app/374320/discussions/0/1744515852428265796/, your Bleed Armor is just how much Bleed Resistance you get from your equipped armor. The only number that matters for determining how much Bleed damage you need to take is the Bleed Resistance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to existing answers:

1. There are offensive and defensive items (see [Consumables](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Consumables), [Projectiles](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Projectiles) and [Ammunition](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Ammunition)) that can:

   - boost your attack status damage (like Carthus Rouge which increases bleed damage);
   - actually apply negative statuses (like Poison Throwing Knife or Poison Arrows);
   - increase resistances (like Mossfruit that boosts bleed, poison, frost and curse resistance);
   - reduce effect bar and clean effects (like Blooming Purple Moss Clump which  cures already applied poison and toxin statuses).
2. There are related Miracles/Sorceris/Pyromancies which:

   - clean effects - like [Caressing Tears](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Caressing+Tears);
   - buff your weapon - like [Frozen Weapon](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Frozen+Weapon);
   - boost resistances - like [Profuse Sweat](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Profuse+Sweat);
   - apply status effect build up - either directly like [Gnaw](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Gnaw), or over time like [Poison Mist](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Poison+Mist).
3. And finally there are some interesting [weapon arts](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Skills) around status effects, for example Storyteller's Staff can create a poisonous cloud which is good for both control and damage.

Knowledge of all these things (and related animations) is quite important if you are going to create a PvP build around one of those. But this is less important in PvE as enemies rarely use any protective spells and their attacks are more predictable.